# JPA/Hibernate @NotFound Ignore not working if ID = 0

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am having trouble with `JPA`. We have a database where not all foreign keys are consistent, so we use `@NotFound(Ignore)`, see code below. But sometimes it throws exceptions like:

> javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find
>   com.kiga.s3.domain.S3Image with id 0

That happens only if the foreign key is `0` (if I change the id to `9999999` in the DB it works). What causes this behavior and what do I need to do to fix it?

Here is our entity code

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFound;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFoundAction;
@Entity
    public class KigaPageImage extends KigaEntityModel {
      @Column(name = "name")
      private String title;
      private String locale;
      private Long imageId;

      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "kigaPageID", referencedColumnName = "id")
      @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
      private KigaPage kigaPage;

      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "s3ImageID", referencedColumnName = "id")
      @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
      private S3Image s3Image;

      public S3Image getS3Image() {
        return s3Image;
      }

      public void setS3Image(S3Image s3Image) {
        this.s3Image = s3Image;
      }
    }
```

S3Image ID generation, does not have a connection to

```
@Entity
public class S3Image{
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "URL")
  private String url;
}
```

regards,
Peter

Comment: @NotFound (whatever that is) is nothing to do with JPA. Perhaps clarify what package it is in

Comment: yeah NotFound and NotFoundAction are both hibernate, I added the imports in the code snippet

Comment: Please provide the entity "S3Image". Does it have an id-generation? If so, on most SQL-servers the auto-increment feature starts at 1... so id = 0 won't exist. if u persist a S3Image with id=0, it will be interpreted as "count up to next available id"

Comment: The Database entries with Index 0 were already in the database, I did not persist them in Javal.

Comment: what hibernate version are you using?

Comment: we are using Hibernate version 4.0.5.Final

Comment: Did you solve the problem? What was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

can you confirm that you are not accessing the Entity within a loop that contains a given Entity multiple times?

I suspect that Hibernate's internal cache might have something to do with it.

Greetings,
Rainer